# Object doesn't support property or method in IE, calling Action script function from javascript, asp.net

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName) {
    debugger;
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        return window[movieName]
    }
    else { return document[movieName] }
}
function helloJS() {

   document.getElementById('myFlashMovie').helloAS("HI");


}

<object width="425" height="344">
    <embed src="testing.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344" id="myFlashMovie"></embed>
</object>
```

I am calling action script function this way, this is working fine in mozilla but throwing error in IE.

Comment: I'm asking for some help here but you've down voted my post. Why??

Comment: try `externalInterface` in as3

Comment: Use SWFObject to embed your Flash. You will see your error go away.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `getFlashMovieObject` function, you have `window[movieName]` and `document[movieName]`.  I would not expect either of these to work.  You will have more luck with the line that you commented out: `var v= document.getElementById("MoveName");`

Comment: Actually he won't. His element only has a name attribute, not an id. He will have more luck with [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName)

Answer (score 0):

I found answer of my question.
i.e.

Try to embed flash this way and you'll be able to call function.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("Flash/testing.swf", "myContent", "500", "500", "9.0.0", "Flash/expressInstall.swf");
    </script>
```